# Problem with select and request.form.get and getlist in Flask

Tags: python, windows, flask, flask-wtforms

My problem is not that serious, just a little bit annoying. I have a dropdown menu and a list of values; however, my values resets themselves to the first option, and I would like for them to remain as the user selected them.

I have read from other sources that the solution is using getlist instead of get, but when I attempt to do it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I have little experience working with flask and Jinga. I guess this must be a problem with the type of values, or some type of name or value that I need to fetch... I honestly have no idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/yBv3ouFxq64) of how the flask is working with request.form.get, and here is the code that I have for that specific html view and the fragment of the app where I am requesting the data.

```py
@app.route('/apuntual', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def apunt():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # This is the button that I click on the video
        if request.form.get('capturar') == 'capturar':
            sample_rate_unf = request.form.get('f_muestreo')
            samples_to_acq_unf = request.form.get('m_canal')
            #Changing the values to int so I can work with them
            sample_rate = int(sample_rate_unf)
            samples_to_acq = int(samples_to_acq_unf)
            #lots of more code in here
            #
            # Sending the output values to make the graph, and some other values to 
            # display in the html
            return render_template('apuntual.html', fmax = fmax, tad = tad, imagen = datos)
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
            
    <form  method="POST">
            
        <h5 class="mb-1">Frecuencia de muestreo</h5>        
        <select name="f_muestreo">
            <option value="2048">2048</option>
            <option value="2560">2560</option>
            <option value="3200">3200</option>
            <option value="5120">5120</option>
        </select>
                
        <h5 class="mb-1">Muestras por canal</h5>
        <select name="m_canal">
            <option value="2048">2048</option>
            <option value="4096">4096</option>
            <option value="8192">8192</option>
        </select>
                    
                
        <h5 class="mb-1">Captura instantánea</h5>
        <p class="bs-component">    
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="capturar" value="capturar">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="borrar" value="borrar">
        </p>
                
        <p class=""bs-component>Frecuencia máxima de: {{ fmax }} Hz con TAD: {{ tad }} ms.</p>  
                    
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand whats your problem? Is your problem value not changing after submission? Because every other things is perfectly working fine.

Comment: `if request.form.get('capturar') == 'capturar':` line is i think unnecessary if you don't have else `borrar` down there. Because it will always be true, nobody is going to change the value of button. And i don't think you have to use `getlist` because getlist is for the multiple selection but according to your code and html, i don't think you need to do that. Finally, what your problem, i had not found anything yet!

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Xitiz, Yes, the program is working just fine, but the dropdown values change back to their initial values (always), I wanted for them to remain as the user previously selected them. As for your other answer, I do have a "borrar" down there, that is just passing x and y values = to 0 for a clear plot. I also have an else condition in case the user decides not to press anything.

Comment: Basically if you want to make that change remain then you have to take that and again send them in front-end. We get value in `sample_rate_unf` and now we have to return this as something ok we will assign `x`, return render_template(" ",x=sample_rate_unf) and in front-end do this `<select name="f_muestreo"> <option value={{x}}>{{x}}>` should I post this as answer?

Comment: answering here, because SO won't let me edit after 5 min ¿? Edit: I tried to implement your code into my app and html. If I include `<option value{{x}}>{{x}}</option>` on the last part of the `<select name="f_muestreo">` I get the values plus a blank one on the bottom, and if I try, just your suggestion without my values, I just get a blank (guess that was logical)... Whenever I click on capturar, I get the following error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Edit your question, what you had tried. I actually tell you to do `<option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>`. I don't know it is typo but you post as `<option value{{x}}>{{x}}</option>` actually try to do `<option value="{{x}}" selected>{{x}}</option>` selected. This will always put this option as selected

Comment: You are getting that error cuz I think as you post there is no attribute value in option and that is selected. And our `sample_rate_unf` gets that selected value and now I am telling you to send data in frontend. And then you will see the result has not been changed(remain same).

Comment: @Xitiz, is working with your suggestion: `<option value="{{x}}" selected>{{x}}</option>`. I did have a typo (was not using the " " for the variable). Right now is working as I was thinking about. Thank you very much! :-D

Answer (score 2):

One solution I can think of is to pass the selected option as a variable to the template and mark the selected option in the template. Here is a demo:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def demo():
    options = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    selected = None
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected = int(request.form.get("something"))
        # Rest of the code goes here

    return render_template("demo.html", options=options, selected=selected)
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <select name="something">
        {% for op in options %}
            {% if selected == op %}
                <option value="{{ op }}" selected>{{ op }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{ op }}">{{ op }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor $}
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Notice that I put all the options as a tuple in the server code. One of reason is to avoid repetitions in the template code. It is also generally considered a bad practice to store data directly to the frontend code like what you are doing here. My demo is not perfect either. A better solution is to put all these options into a configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @AlpacaMax, I implemented your code into my app and my html. It's not marking me any errors, but I can't see any of the options. I recorded a [video](https://youtu.be/M5yVUANNsGs) of it. I ommited the .css code (thinking that it was a problem with formatting), but is still the same (can't see the options in the dropdown menu).

Comment: No problem @Eduardo. There could be a typo somewhere in your code. Check if you actually pass the options into the template and if there is a typo in the for loop in the template.